# How to enable service for graphical.target only on systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to enable bluetooth service, only for the graphical.target, alias runlevel 5.

I'm on Debian Jessie, it's using systemd.

I was told to create a symlink in the /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants directory, but i'm still a bit lost.

i have already tried using update-rc.d, didn't work.

in /etc/systemd/system, there is a folder called bluetooth.service.wants, there's a bluetooth.service file in there, which contains the unit informations.

there's also another .service file in /etc/systemd/system which is actually an alias for the original bluetooth.service.
thanks

Comment: Explain with an [edit] of your answer what you have already tried please.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301987/how-to-create-a-systemd-target) on Unix.SE provides a good overview on how to create a custom target.

Apparently, you cannot easily override the `[Install]` section of a systemd unit. It defines which target “will want” the unit.

```
~ # systemctl enable apcupsd
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apcupsd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/apcupsd.service.

~ # cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/apcupsd.service
[Unit]
Description=APC UPS Monitor

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/apcupsd -b

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see, enabling a unit (not just a service!) is as simple as creating a symlink. Now when systemd is told to start `multi-user.target` it will also start `apcupsd.service`.

So you first need to find out where `bluetooth.service` is located. I’ll assume it’s at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`. Then you just need to:

```
~ # ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/bluetooth.service
```

If the `graphical.target.wants` directory does not exist, you need to create it first.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try it out and tell you if it works !